# How to remove postgresql json_build_object header to make into valid json

Tags: json, postgresql, bash, psql

For example it returns

```
json_build_object

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
{"Customer: [{"id": 21, "name: "Dev"}]}
1 row
```

This is not valid json. How would you remove everything so that only {"Customer": [{"id": 21, "name": "Dev"}]} is returned.

Comment: why unix, sed, bash tags?

Comment: `{"Customer: [{"id": 21, "name: "Dev"}]}` is also not valid JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Use the option `--tuples-only` when starting `psql`, then the header won't be printed.